# Could we add a google+1 button?

Tags: feature-request

I noticed there was a facebook, a twitter, even a linkedln button to share a link towards a question, but there is no Google's +1 button. Admittedly, Google+ is quite young and could know the future of, say, Google Buzz, but many, many people in the programming businesses already have an account there. Couldn't we add this ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97406/any-plans-supporting-google-for-link-sharing-in-the-near-future

Comment: Didn't see it, sorry. You can close the question.

Comment: +1 is not the same as share-on-Google+, so this question as stated is different. Currently, there is a share button but no +1 button.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the linked answer, Google+ does not support simple link sharing and we cannot support them until they do.

Comment: Well, let's hope they'll support it ! Thank you very much for taking the time to answer.